# Testing an event with a timestamp arg

Tags: solidity, testing, hardhat

I'm trying to write a test using waffle, but I'm not sure how to assert that a timestamp is correct in an emitted event.

My event looks like this:

```
event BeginJourney (
    uint256 indexed departFrom,
    uint256 indexed arriveAt,
    uint256 indexed arrivalTime
);
```

which is emitted like this in the contract:

```
emit BeginJourney(currentId, newId, block.timestamp + travelTime);
```

My test so far looks like this:

```
await expect(city.connect(acc1).travelTo(1))
    .to.emit(city, "BeginJourney").withArgs(0, 1, ???);
```

Using Waffle's `.withArgs` assertation, I can only check exact values. What I really want is to check that the 3rd timestamp arg is within a few seconds of the current epoch time plus some constant.

Is there any way to code this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `chai`'s `.closeTo` method. You can read the documentation for it here:
https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_closeto

You'll have to parse the transaction receipt yourself though, instead of using `expect().to.emit()`.

I assume you're using `ethers`, in which case the way to extract the event-logs for that particular event is:

`receipt.events?.filter((x)=>{return x.event=='BeginJourney'});`

This returns an array of 'BeginJourney' events.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually code the "is in the range test".

Something like;

```
 assert(timesStamp + offset < maxlimit & timesStamp - offset > minlit)
```

Basically any logic that can be true or false.